# UITextField: Keyboard appear, just if I click in the left side of it

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Why is it, then the keyboard appear, just if I clicked in the right part of the UITextField?

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
EditableCell* cell = [[EditableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.reportViewController = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.text = item.text;

UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
textfield.text = item.var.value;
textfield.tag = 1;
textfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
textfield.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1];
textfield.delegate = cell;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textfield];
return cell;
```

layoutSubviews:

```
UITextField* textfield = (UITextField *)[self viewWithTag:1];
textfield.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x+self.textLabel.frame.size.width+10, 
                             self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                             tableView.frame.size.width-(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x+self.textLabel.frame.size.width)-20, 
                             self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
```

views structure with the 'Color Blended Layers'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something else (Other UI item) covering the left side of your UITextField?

You can use the simulator with the 'Color Blended Layers' feature to show if there is anything ontop of your UITextField

Comment: Color Blended Layers is really smart, but nothing above the UITextField.

Comment: That was an other view covering the TableView. The funny, that it was set to hidden, but also accidentally I bring It to front so it was interfere with this TableView.